# RewriteRule in VHost explanation

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

What does this line means and what does it do?

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can find Official Documentation for `mod_rewrite` here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html